# How can I make the design view correspond with InitializeComponent code?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I have imported a form from another project. If I run the program, everything corresponds with the code. 
The design view, however, looks like a blank form. 
Can I refresh the design view so that it shows the components initialized in my `InitializeComponent()` method?

Comment: Maybe you can check if the following code is missing in Designer.cs. Such as `this.Controls.Add(this.button1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing some references? I had a similar issue, but not with copy paste. I redesigned my design view and anyhow visual stuio lost some code in the designer file and therefore no controls and designed controls were visible anymore. So I had to redsign the form and copy the working code into it.

At least, it is not good to copy and paste a whole project. Design your own forms and only put the source code into it.

Comment: All I did was to "Add Existing...". After pressing that I added the Form.cs, Form.Designer.cs and Form.resx files.

Comment: Yes and I think there occurred an error and not all information have been correctly processed by visual studio. Try to create a new form and only copy the source code of form.cs into your new form.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please vote my answer with arrow up, if I could help. Thank you.

Comment: I got back to my project and tried what you said in your first comment. That fixed it for me.